# Does erasing an element from a vector by replacing it with the last element and then removing it makes the process faster?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have a vector of integers and i want to erase an element from it.
I read that by "erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions.", I don't care about the position of the integers.
Is it faster if i replaced the last element with the one that i wanna erase and then erase the last element ?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is how you should do it if you don't care about the element order.